# Efficiently take one value for each key out of a RDD[(key,value)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My starting point is an RDD[(key,value)] in Scala using Apache Spark. The RDD contains roughly 15 million tuples. Each key has roughly 50+-20 values.

Now I'd like to take one value (doesn't matter which one) for each key. My current approach is the following:

1. HashPartition the RDD by the key. (There is no significant skew)
2. Group the tuples by key resulting in RDD[(key, array of values)]]
3. Take the first of each value array

Basically looks like this:

```
...
candidates
.groupByKey()
.map(c => (c._1, c._2.head)
...
```

The grouping is the expensive part. It is still fast because there is no network shuffle and candidates is in memory but can I do it faster?

My idea was to work on the partitions directly, but I'm not sure what I get out of the HashPartition. If I take the first tuple of each partition, I will get every key but maybe multiple tuples for a single key depending on the number of partitions? Or will I miss keys?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `reduceByKey` with a function that returns the first argument? Like this:

```
candidates.reduceByKey((x, _) => x)
```

Comment: Yields the correct result. Let me see what it changes performance wise, any predictions?

Comment: In general, it can affect the performance significantly. For your restriction (30-70 values per key) it should not be much.

Comment: This is a bit hacky since reduce should be used with commutative and associative functions.

Comment: @user52045 It is easy to make it commutative by changing `(x, _) => x` to `(x, y) => x max y`